# Why is my custom PropertyItem not able to be pulled out of the Image?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I have a custom PropertyItem that I've "created" and stored some values in within an image. I'm positive that it's correctly storing it because the new image will increase in size, (depending on how big I make the string).

--[Question is at the bottom]--

Here's the code in which I put the PropertyItem into the image.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image); //image is of type Image
string s = "Hello there";
var pi = createPropertyItem();
pi.Id = 40091;
pi.Len = s.Length+1; //don't worry too much about this - this is a test case,
                     //not the real types and lengths. If I put an error in here,
                     //it's not what's making it error out elsewhere. :)
pi.Type = 2;
pi.Value = s;
bmp.SetPropertyItem(pi);

bmp.Save("image.jpg", bmp.RawFormat);//is this actually saving the PropertyItems
                                     //into the file, "image.jpg"?
```

Anyways, I'm having trouble elsewhere - I need to extract the value from the PropertyItem of the image. However:

```
Bitmap thing = new Bitmap("image.jpg"); // is this the problem code?
String newString = getStringOut(thing);

/////////////////further down in the program//////////////////////////

public String getStringOut(Image image)
{
    var x = image.GetPropertyItem(40091); //this fails because the PropertyItem
                                          //is not in this image.
    string s = x.Value;
}
```

My question is: since the PropertyItem is in the image that's saved (at least it appears to be, since the file's size gets larger the longer the string I put in), why is it NOT being accessed by my method, (getStringOut), when I go back and try and retrieve the PropertyItem from the saved image? When I initialize the new Bitmap, is it not pulling the EXIF data for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050936/resize-an-image-and-keeping-metadata-property-item). Turns out that my line of code with the comment: `// is this the problem code?` **is** the problem code, because this is stripping out the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.setpropertyitem.aspx) - essentially, copying a property item and changing its ID before setting it?

Also, you might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396050/set-image-meta-data-before-save).  The author doesn't attempt (or doesn't describe himself as attempting) to retrieve his property item, but he uses some different techniques and PropertyItem property values than you do (in his answer).

Comment: I have tried that method - I think I'm using Image.SetPropertyItem() pretty explicitly.
I have already seen that question and its answer, and you will see that I use his method (the use of CreatePropertyItem(), for instance) in my program. He does use different techniques and PropertyItem property values than I do, but as I said in the comments, that is not the question I'm asking.

Comment: @arthur.e.anderson  Ah, and you said you weren't showing your real data and lengths.  It seemed to me that if you weren't putting in what you thought you were putting in, you might have a hard time getting what you expected out. Hence the suggestion of different values.

Comment: **My question has still not been answered.**
Since the PropertyItem is in the image that's saved, why is it NOT being accessed by my method once I go back and try and retrieve the PropertyItem from that image?